# Compute the integral using Riemann sums.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

Let $f(x)= 1 , \;-1\leqslant x\gt0,\; f(x)= 2,\; x=0,\; f(x)= 1 ,\; 0\lt x\leqslant1.$
Compute this integral using Riemann sums:
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Any tips/solutions? I don't even know what the function is, so I can't find $f(x_i)$ etc but $\Delta x$ is $2/n$, I think, and $x_i$ is $-1 + 2i/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rewrite the function as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & -1\le x<0\\2 & x=0\\1 & 0<x\le 1.\end{cases}$$ Then indeed, putting $\Delta x=\frac2n$ and $x_i=-1+\frac{2i}{n}$ for $1\le i\le n,$ we have that $f(x_i)=1$ if and only if $x_i\ne 0,$ and $f(x_i)=2$ otherwise. Note that if $n$ is odd, then we will have $f(x_i)=1$ for all $i.$ However, if $n$ is even--say $n=2m$--then $f(x_m)=2,$ and $f(x_i)=1$ for $i\ne m.$

From this, you should be able to see that, regardless of $n,$ we have that $$2\le\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x\le 2+\frac2n.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: what do you mean with lower sum and partition? sorry my english is not that good

Comment: Apologies. I see you're using a different definition of Riemann sum. I will reformulate my answer.

Comment: idk what definition im supposed to use -.- I dont use definitions I mean...

Comment: Answer edited. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I still cant see how you get that expressions

Comment: Which expressions do you mean? I'm glad to discuss the details with you, but you'll have to be more specific about which parts are confusing you.

Comment: the whole last thing man

Comment: I can only do basic example on this not when idk what the function is etc, but if its x^2 +x +1 etc then easy

Comment: Ah! So you're not familiar with piecewise functions?

Comment: I have seen it before on continious problems etc, but not in riemann sums

Comment: I see. Well, fortunately, this one isn't too complicated. Do you see why $f(x_i)=1$ if $x_i\ne 0$ and $f(x_i)=2$ if $x_i=0$?

Comment: yes, same thing as f(x) right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's just how $f$ is defined. Do you see why $x_i\ne 0$ unless $n$ is even and $i=\frac{n}2$?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Since $x_i=-1+\frac{2i}{n},$ then the following are equivalent: $$x_i=0\\\frac{2i}{n}=1\\2i=n\\i=\frac{n}2.$$ Since $i,n$ are integers, the last equation tells us not only that $i=\frac{n}2,$ but also that $n$ is even. Does that make sense?

Comment: ahh ok so when I got functions like this I need to find out its even or odd?

Comment: ok so x_1=0 now what?

Comment: Not always, but in this case, we need to know when $x_i=0,$ since that's the only time we'll ever have $f(x_i)=2.$ It turns out that $x_i=0$ if and only if $n$ is even and $i=\frac n2.$ In general, it's good to know which $x_i$ make the piecewise function $f$ refer to which of its rules, since otherwise, we don't have any way to find the sum.

Comment: Anyway, siince $f(x_i)=1$ for $x_i\ne 0$ and $f(x_i)=2$ for $x_i=0,$ do you see why for odd $n,$ we have $f(x_i)=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: yeah that just what the function is defined for isnt it

Comment: Yes. So what is $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x$$ when $n$ is odd?

Comment: 1*deltax=2/n right?

Comment: True, so $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac2n=?$$

Comment: I mean thats just 2? since I get n/n

Comment: Yes! It's just $2$.

Comment: what do you mean with different 2/n's?

Comment: That is exactly where the $2$ came from. So, when $n$ is odd, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)=2<2+\frac2n.$$ So, the inequality holds in the case that $n$ is odd. With me so far?

Comment: 2<2+2/n. how did you get that?

Comment: Since $n>0,$ then $0<\frac2n,$ and so $2<2+\frac2n.$

Comment: yeah but how do you get 2 + 2/n??

Comment: We'll see where the $2+\frac2n$ came from in just a moment. Now let's suppose that $n$ is even. As we saw above, $f(x_{n/2})=2$ and $f(x_i)=1$ for $i\ne\frac{n}2,$ right?

Comment: yeah t hast right

Comment: Okay, so, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=\bigl(f(x_{n/2})-1\bigr)\Delta x+\sum_{i=1}^n1\cdot\Delta x,$$ yes?

Comment: ok, but why -1?

Comment: man please give me full solution + explanation :O! :D, I can understand it much better then

Comment: I'm working on the explanation, now. Please be patient. As for where the $-1$ came from, do you understand why the following equalities hold? $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x &= \sum_{i=1}^n\bigl(f(x_i)-1+1\bigr)\Delta x\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n\bigl(f(x_i)-1\big)\Delta x+\sum_{i=1}^n1\cdot\Delta x\end{align}$$

Comment: ahh yeah! thanks! :P

Comment: I tought this problem would be much easier to solve when I first asked the question :P

Comment: Good. Now, we already know that if $i\ne n/2,$ then $f(x_i)=1,$ so $f(x_i)-1=0.$ That's why we have $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=\bigl(f(x_{n/2})-1\bigr)\Delta x+\sum_{i=1}^n1\cdot\Delta x.$$ Just like before, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n1\cdot\Delta x=2,$$ and so $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=2+\bigl(f(x_{n/2})-1\bigr)\Delta x,$$ but since $f(x_{n/2})=2,$ then $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=2+\Delta x=2+\frac2n.$$

Comment: *That's* where the $+\frac2n$ comes from. Anyway, when $n$ is odd, we have $$2<2+\frac2n=\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x.$$ Putting the odd and even cases together, we have $$2\le\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x\le 2+\frac2n$$ for all $n.$

Comment: Can you see what to do from here? (Incidentally, this problem is fairly easy, but you need to have a few more advanced results to make it easy.)

Comment: limn->infinity of 2≤2+ 2/n ≤ 2+ 2/n?

Comment: so I get 2≤2≤2 :P

Comment: That's pretty close to the idea. Since $$2\le\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x\le 2+\frac2n$$ for all $n,$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}[2]\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x\right]\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[2+\frac2n\right].$$ How would you rewrite the left-hand side? The right-hand side? The middle?

Comment: idk! nothign makes sense.. the middle thing is exactly the same as the right thing*

Comment: Sorry. Let me rephrase. What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}[2]$? What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[2+\frac2n\right]$?

Comment: its just 2 and 2+0?

Comment: Right, but $2+0=2.$ So, we have $$2\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x\right]\le 2,$$ which means that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x\right]=2.$$ Still with me?

Comment: yeah tahts what I said like 5 comments ago lol?

Comment: No. You said $$\lim_{n\to\infty}[2]\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[2+\frac2n\right] \le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[2+\frac2n\right].$$ This is true, but it isn't helpful, since $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x$$ is *not always equal to $2+\frac2n$*.

Comment: YEAH BUT ITS EQUAL  to 2 or 2+2/n?

Comment: Finally, since $$\int_{-1}^1f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x\right]=2,$$ then we're done. It's a bear of a problem when you're using sums like this. Believe me when I say it could have been worse if the piecewise function had been at all complicated. I'm sorry it took so long, but that's the best we can do with the most basic tools.

Comment: thanks man, I was getting a bit salty at the end there knowing I have spdnt well over 3hours on just this one question eventho I know how to do most of these kind of problems, but not for piecewise functions :(